I can't configure OpenCV to use FFMPEG in python docker image
I am attempting to create a Python Docker image to utilize OpenCV for processing video frame by frame, but I am encountering difficulties with the codec. Gives this erro:
[ERROR:0@38.410] global cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:3130 open Could not find encoder for codec_id=27, error: Encoder not found [ERROR:0@38.410] global cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:3208 open VIDEOIO/FFMPEG: Failed to initialize VideoWriter
my docker file:
# Use a base image with the necessary dependencies
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Install ffmpeg and other dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y


# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app/ai_model

# Copy the requirements file to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt .


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-server-dev-all

# Install the required dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    grep -v -e opencv requirements.txt | pip install --no-cache-dir -r /dev/stdin && \
    pip install  --no-cache-dir onnxruntime-gpu==1.14.0 && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code to the working directory
COPY . .

# Expose the port on which the app will run
EXPOSE 8080

# Define the command to run the app
CMD ["python", "app.py"]

`
I am aware that OpenCV does not inherently support the h264 codec, yet I require video support for HTML player integration. I have found that when running on Windows, utilizing the 'av1' codec with 'openh263-1.8.0-win64.dll' from Cisco resolves the issue.Cisco
Consequently, I have endeavored to incorporate the same codec into the Python Docker image, but to no avail. The container reports an error indicating that it cannot locate the codec.
Thanks for your time.

Is the host PC Windows? Try installing opencv using conda. conda install -c conda-forge opencv

opencv does use an arbitrary ffmpeg you installed in the system. opencv needs to be built to use a specific ffmpeg. the information has to be there at build time. official opencv-python packages do come with ffmpeg, but that ffmpeg doesn't come with libx264. it can decode but not encode. IP licensing forbids this.

@HOBE use conda in docker build? How can I write this?

@Jrneliodias check here to install conda in Dockerfile
